# Combining "with" and "url" Django Template Tags

Tags: django, django-templates

Django has two template tags "with" and "url".  It would be handy to be able to combine the two:

```
{% with view=really.long.path.to.some.view.somewhere %}
    {% url view.foo %}
{% endwith %}
```

But if you try doing that, you find out that the "with" isn't getting applied inside the "url" tag (as you get an error about there not being a "view.foo").

So, my question is, am I just missing some flag/option/alternative format that would make the above work, or is truly impossible to simplify "url" tags using "with"?

Comment: This is a pretty interesting use-case of `with` didn't know this was possible. But in most cases I'd rather sidestep the need for such, by declaring named URL patterns and using those names in `url` instead of long.path.to.view

Comment: Yeah, named url patterns are definitely the way to go in general.  I'm working on a legacy codebase which has a whole bunch of urls printed out on the page (for the Javascript to use), and naming each one would be a giant pain.  Being able to use "with" to make them all a bit shorter/easier to read in one fell swoop is definitely preferable for now (and then someday we will likely go back and name them all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in Django 1.3 if you're willing to use a future compatibility library.

See the section *Forwards compatibility* at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url (just above the discussion on widthratio) for an explanation and examples.

Comment: Man I love it when I have a problem with a library and find out the library's developers have already solved said problem; thanks for the info.